# Locate the largest element and swap with the first in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to locate the largest element of `r2` and swap it with the element at `r2[0,0]`. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
r2 = np.array([[  1.00657843,  63.38075613, 312.87746691],
       [375.25164461, 500.        , 125.75493382],
       [437.6258223 , 250.50328922, 188.12911152]])
indices = np.where(r2 == r2.max())
```

The expected output is

```
array([[  500.,  63.38075613, 312.87746691],
       [375.25164461,  1.00657843, 125.75493382],
       [437.6258223 , 250.50328922, 188.12911152]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the maximum value in a variable, and then assign the `[0, 0]` element to the indices which you found with `where` and then set the `[0, 0]` element to the stored maximum value:

```
maximum = r2.max()
indices = np.where(r2 == maximum)
r2[indices] = r2[0, 0]
r2[0, 0] = maximum
r2
```

Output:

```
array([[500.        ,  63.38075613, 312.87746691],
       [375.25164461,   1.00657843, 125.75493382],
       [437.6258223 , 250.50328922, 188.12911152]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just return the index of the largest value and then swap with first index

```
# get index of largest value. 
index = np.unravel_index(r2.argmax(), r2.shape)
# swap with item at index 0,0
r2[index], r2[0,0] = r2[0,0], r2[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### In this way you will replace all the element that have the max value

```
#get the max value of the array
max_value = np.max(r2)
#all the element with the max value will be replaced with the first value
r2[r2 == max_value] = r2[0][0]
#put the max value in the first position
r2[0][0] = max_value
```